# SharePoint calculated column IF statement w/ colour indicator

Tags: list-view, calculated-column

Any hints/idea why the following formula shows no result, empty column?

Rating Graph Column

```
="<span style='height:1ex,width:"&(10*1)&"px,border:1px green green,background-color:"&IF(Rating="Goals achieved","#088A08",IF(Rating="Underperformed","#DF0101"))&",display:inline-block,'></span>"&"<span style='height:1ex,width:"&(10-10*1)&"px,border:1px transparent solid,display:inline-block,'></span>"
```

Column Rating with the choices Goals achieved and Underperformed

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

what is your return type? Try Number to make sure it renders the HTML. Also use semicolons in between your parameters, not commas.

```
="<span style='height:1ex;width:"&(10*1)&"px;border:1px green green;background-color:"&IF(Rating="Goals achieved","#088A08",IF(Rating="Underperformed","#DF0101"))&";display:inline-block;'></span>"&"<span style='height:1ex;width:"&(10-10*1)&"px;border:1px transparent solid;display:inline-block;'></span>"
```